# How to implement logging in workflow

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I'm using WF 4.0 and how I can implement logging errors, audit information in workflows. Please give me some ideas or references.

UPDATE: The workflows are hosted as services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three approaches:

1. Read here on workflow tracking: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513992%28VS.100%29.aspx
2. Windows Server AppFabric has a good monitoring framework for WF4.
3. Just chuck log4net in.

I'd pick 2 over anything as it works out of the box.